# Using custom image buttons to display an image in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, image, imagebutton

I am creating a text editor much like notepad/word and i have buttons on my form with custom images attached. The images have been loaded into the resource folder. Now when i click the button i want it to display that same image in the RichTextBox, the images being displayed will be various emoticons. I only found ways to create picture viewers and not this.

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{       
   Image.FromFile("../../Resources/sad-icon.png");    
}
```

This will be used to place a sad emoticon in the RichTextBox. This is what i have so far i am pretty new to C#.

Comment: Are you working in WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying various methods and i found one that works but only with certain emoticons and not the emoticons that i need to be able to use.

```
        void InsertEmoticon(string ImageName)
        {
            int StringLength = 0;
            StringLength = txtPAD.Text.Length;
            Image img = Image.FromFile("../../Resources/Emoticons/" + ImageName + ".png");
            Clipboard.SetImage(img);
            txtPAD.SelectionStart = (StringLength + 1);
            txtPAD.Paste();
            txtPAD.Clear();
        }
```

I will then use:

```
 private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InsertEmoticon("glad");
    }
```

Am i missing something here? The images have been loaded into the resource folder and are inside the folder Emoticons.